# Android project Gradle and Jack Build Toolchain : The import cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jack

I have an Android project and I use Android Studio. In this project, I have the main app (cdmandroidclient) and the SDK (cdmsdk) which is the core lib.

I added recently a library built with Java 8 into my Android project. So I had to change a few things into my Gradle files :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.cdmandroidclient"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':cdmsdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

As you can see, I import into my app, the cdmsdk module, which is part of my project. Before using Jack, everything was fine.

Now, when I try to build the app I get errors for resolving dependencies of my module "**cdmsdk**" into my app "**cdmandroidclient**".

Exemple of an error :

> Error:E:\Workspace\CDMAndroidClient\app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\cdmandroidclient\service\CdmService.java:16:
>   The import com.mycompany.cdmsdk.heartbeat.Security cannot be resolved

I don't understand what's happening, because the main app dependencies have not changed and still reference the SDK with :

```
compile project(path: ':cdmsdk')
```

The Gradle build fail as I said, during the task **:app:compileDebugJavaWithJack**

Any idea ? Thank you very much :) !

EDIT : It's the exact same thing as Javac and with Java 7... don't know what I've changed but my app can't use cdmsdk dependencies anymore ... wtf

Comment: compile project(':library_project') , remove that "#path"

Comment: @Radhey I tried it didn't change the error ... I cleaned my project and tried restart Android Studio. However, with or without path seems to be the same

Comment: i hope you deleted .jar of cdmsdk ,if was  in your lib folder !!

Comment: @Radhey it's automatically deleted, yes. Each time I rebuild the app. Because I've put the cdmsdk into "Compile" dependency mode.

Comment: Interesting ! ,you are going in right way but still , can you plz tell me for what purpose you are using   jackOptions { enabled true  } ?

Comment: Because without this enabled, Gradle fail to compile your Java 8 code. And I use a dependency which has been built with Java 8, and I have no other alternative :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126333/discussion-between-radhey-and-alex).